# Deleting node from generic tree

Tags: java, tree

I can't write correctly function that deletes one node from tree. If this node has children, they should move one level higher. Children of deleted element will have parent of deleted elem,ancestors will they on they places, but one level higher. How can I do it right?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Node<T> {
    private T value;
    private final List<Node<T>> listOfChildren;

    private Node<T> parent;

    public Node(){
        super();
        listOfChildren = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Node(T value){
        this();
        setValue(value);
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setParent(Node<T> parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<Node<T>> getListOfChildren() {
        return listOfChildren;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getNumberOfChildren() {
        return listOfChildren.size();
    }

    public void addChildren(Node<T> child) {
        parent = this;
        listOfChildren.add(child);
    }


    public void removeChildAt(int index) {
        if (index > listOfChildren.size()-1){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "This index is too big");
        }
        else {
            Node<T> element = this.listOfChildren.get(index);
            if (element.listOfChildren.size() > 0) {
                // function...
            }
            listOfChildren.remove(index);
        }
    }

}
```

I think that writing dfs or bfs to walk through the tree is not the best way to realize this function. What is the best way to realize this function?

Comment: _Can I do it without parent field in my node_. No, you can't.

Comment: Your specifications do not provide a way to delete the root node of the tree, at least not when that node has two or more children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Children of deleted element will keep their descendants, so no walk through required

```
    public void removeChildAt(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (listOfChildren != null) {
            Node<T> element = this.listOfChildren.get(index);
            if (element.listOfChildren.size() > 0) {
                this.listOfChildren.addAll(element.listOfChildren);
                //element.listOfChildren.forEach(child -> child.setParent(this)); but you have no backward reference to parent
            }
            listOfChildren.remove(index);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No children from this node");
        }
    }
```